# How to separate words within a long string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this string variable

```
var mySentence = "EverythingIsAwesome";
```

I want it to output: "Everything Is Awesome"

I tried doing `mySentence.split(" ");` but it stays the same. Then I tried: `mySentence.split(" ").join(" ");` but it still keeps the sentence together.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no space between the words so how would the split work?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `match()` like this:

```
mySentence.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g);
```

You will get this array: `['Everything', 'Is', 'Awesome']` 
To turn it back into a string simply: `mySentence.join("");`